# Having trouble getting a custom directivein a SPA

Tags: angularjs

I have a base Angular SPA ('app').  Within that app, I would like to make use of an ng image slider that I found.  The example of the slider is a custom directive which is perfect.  It is my understanding that I should be able to implement a custom directive within an Angular app, and it stands independently.  However, it is also my understanding that in a SPA, there can be only ONE Angular app.  The example of the slider is not only a custom directive, but it is also an app.  I have been trying repeatedly to de-couple the directive from the app so that I can apply it in my base app, without success of course.

Here is the index.html of the base app:

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello VSLive 2015

    <div>
      <a ng-href="/">Customer</a>
    </div>

    <ng-view></ng-view>

    <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="routes.js"></script>
    <script src="customer.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="customer-detail.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="customer.service.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the app declaration in the base app:

```
(function () {
  angular
.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
})()
```

Here are my questions.

## 1, In my introduction to custom directives, the controller was within the directive.  In the slider example, it is outside.  If I take this line of code, outside the directive in the example:

```
    sliderApp.controller('SliderController', function($scope) {
$scope.images=[{src:'img1.png',title:'Pic 1'},{src:'img2.jpg',title:'Pic 2'},{src:'img3.jpg',title:'Pic 3'},{src:'img4.png',title:'Pic 4'},   {src:'img5.png',title:'Pic 5'}];   });
```

and move it inside the directive list this:

```
  controller: function ($scope) {
  $scope.images = [{ src: 'img1.png', title: 'Pic 1' }, { src: 'img2.jpg', title: 'Pic 2' }, { src: 'img3.jpg', title: 'Pic 3' }, { src: 'img4.png', title: 'Pic 4' }, { src: 'img5.png', title: 'Pic 5' }];
```

}

is that valid and correct?

## 2, I changed the declaration of the directive from this (in the example)

```
sliderApp.directive('slider', function ($timeout) {
  return {
```

to this

```
angular
  .module('app.directives.slider', ['ngAnimate'])
  .directive('slider', function ($timeout) {
     return {
```

Finally, I added my references to the Angular Animate.  In the example, it is required like this:

```
var sliderApp=angular.module('sliderApp',['ngAnimate']);
```

I tried putting it in the initial app declaration like this:

```
(function () {
  angular
  .module('app', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);
})()
```

and then in the directive:

```
    angular
  .module('app.directives.slider', ['ngAnimate'])
  .directive('slider', function ($timeout) {
       return {
```

The first way the app stops working for me (no error).  The second way, the slider does not work.  The final implementation of the directive is as follows in the example:

```
     <body ng-controller="SliderController">
     <h1>Slider Using AngularJS</h1>
     <slider images="images"/>
   </body>
```

I'm expecting that by moving the controller the way I did I can do this:

```
 <div>
   <h1>Slider Using AngularJS</h1>
   <slider images="images"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your code, but the question is a little messy, can you please post also the actual structure of your html file and your jss?

Answer (score 0):

By what I can see actually in your question I think that the problem can be that you are not referencing your slider module inside the html.

in the html tag you have:

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

but your module (that is the only one) is declared like this:

```
(function () {
  angular
  .module('app', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);
})()
```

There is no reference to your `app.directive.slider` module. I think that you will go a step nearer the goal if you include in your dependencies that module.

```
(function () {
  angular
  .module('app', ['ngRoute','app.directive.slider']);
})()
```

given the fact that `app.directive.slider` already include ngAnimate dependency you don't need to declare that in your main app (you have to if you are using it also in your app).

I will update my answer if you will post new code

Comment: Sorry, i did not include that piece of code.  I actually added reference to the directive in index.html as follows         <script src="directives/slider.js"></script>

Comment: that's not enough, you need to add it as dependency in the main module (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

My issue had to do with an improper version-ed angular-animate.js